# Wordpress Custome-post-type / need advise for single-posttype.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I would bang my head against the wall trying to find a solution for my problem: 
I'm using Wordpress 3.0 and have a custom post type call 'movie'. 
I have a single-movie.php file that display the information about the movie like:the_excerpt,cover-image,and some meta info. Now I want to have a 'read more' button that display the full story of the movie but I don't know how to do it. 
Can somebody tell me what I need to do to have a full-story page for a single movie post type?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you could look at doing something like the following:

add this to your functions.php

```
function is_post_type($type){
    global $wp_query;
    if($type == get_post_type($wp_query->post->ID)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

and then add the following to your single.php

```
if (is_single() && is_post_type('post_type')){
  //work magic
}
```

Comment: Thank so much Danyo. I'll try your solution and report you result.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try

```
if (is_singular() && is_post_type('post_type')) {
    //work magic
}
```

or just

```
if (is_singular('post_type')) {
    //work magic
}
```